# How to debug wanpipe driver?

Tags: drivers

I need to learn about how to debug wanpipe driver? If anyone know about this please give me reference for debugging wanpipe driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following url for debugging wanpipe driver.

http://wiki.sangoma.com/wanpipe-wan-operation